# Cannot access class. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, braintree-sandbox

I am a beginner in android studio, but i have to do some not-so-beginner stuff. I am building an app that uses braintree payments, anything related to braintree needs to be separate from the main app so i put it in an android library. The problem is I cannot access classes that are in the library from the main app, for example, in the library i have a class with this function [getDropInRequest function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mreVE.png)

When i try to call the function from the main app I get no errors
[Calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuJ9s.png)

But when i try to build the project i get this error:
[error when building the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZJmw.png)

When i make a simple function, like for adding two numbers it works fine, so i guess i have written the function in a wrong way or there is a problem with dependencies. These are the dependencies i am using in the main app: [main app dependancies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAMQr.png). In the braintree library i am only using **implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1'.**.

I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, reloading the project, making a fresh project from scratch but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.